# CDF and Convergence of Maximum of Sequence of i.i.d. R.V. of Random Length

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d random variable $U(0,1)$ distributed.  Let $N_m$ be $Poisson(m)$ and independent of each $X_i$.

i)Find the cumulative density function of $M_{m}=max(X_1,X_2,...,X_{N_{m}})$.

ii)Then show that $w=m(1-M_m) \to exp(1)$ as $m \to \infty$ in distribution.

My book shows an example of a somewhat similar problem but the sequence is not of random length, so the CDF ends up being the CDF of the distribution of each variable in the sequence raised to the power of the length of the sequence.  I am unsure how to tackle this problem when the sequence is of random length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given** that $N_m=k$, where $k\ge 1$, and $0\lt x\lt 1$, we have 
$$\Pr(M_m\le x)=x^k.$$
Now we need to decide what $\Pr(M_m\le x)$ is if $N_m=0$. There is no obvious definition. With not much conviction, we call this probability $1$. Then
$$\Pr(M_m\le x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-m} \frac{m^k}{k!}x^k.$$
We recognize the sum as $e^{-m}e^{mx}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get the second part using the CDF, too!

Comment: You are welcome. It is a very good thing that you were  able to handle (ii) on your own.